# Logically matching vectors of character strings of different sizes

Tags: r

So I have a few data frames all made up of multiple character strings of different sizes. The first data frame has all character strings in it, all following data frames a data frame made up of a subset of that original frame. I want to form something like a true/false table to for matching strings in the subsetted data frames and I'm unsure how to do it.

```
 x <- c("A", "B", "C")
 y <- c("A", "C")
 z <- c("C")

 > final.data.frame 
     y   z
 A   1   0
 B   0   0
 C   1   1
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think the 'y' column should be `1 0 1`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right in that I forgot a 1. May the forces of evil become confused and lost on the way to your home!

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
res <- sapply(list(y= y, z= z), function(u) as.integer(x %in% u))
row.names(res) <- x
res
#  y z
#A 1 0
#B 0 0
#C 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t(sapply(x, function(a)
    data.frame(y = as.numeric(a %in% y), z = as.numeric(a %in% z))))
#  y z
#A 1 0
#B 0 0
#C 1 1
```